# How to find multiple files with different ending in LInux using regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

Let's say that I have multiple files such as:

```
root.file991
root.file81
root.file77
root.file989
```

If I want to delete all of them, I would need to use a regex first, so I have tried:

```
find ./ - regex '\.\/root'
```

...which would find everything in root file, but how do I filter all these specific files?

Comment: The immediate problem is the space between `-` and `regex`, and the fact that your regular expression is wrong (though perhaps that's what you were obscurely trying to ask about?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```bash
find ./ -regextype posix-extended -regex '\./root\.file[0-9]+'
```

The regex will match paths like

- `\.` - a dot
- `/root\.file` -  a `/root.file` text
- `[0-9]+` - ending with one or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *"files in root file"* but if I understand correctly regular POSIX `glob(7)` pattern matching should be sufficient:

```
rm root.file[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex the other files are, you may have to build up the regex more. `$ man find` has useful help as well. Try the following:

```bash
$ find ./ -regex '\.\/root.file[0-9].*'

# if that works to find what you are looking for, add the -delete
$ find ./ -regex '\.\/root.file[0-9].*' -delete
```